# Merging objects with twig overwrite results rather than adding them together

Tags: gulp, twig

How can I combine these to objects:

```
{% set stuff1 = {
  array: [
    {
      one: 'A',
      two: 'B'
    }
  ]
}
%}

{% set stuff2 = {
  array: [
    {
      one: 'C',
      two: 'D'
    }
  ]
}
%}
```

So that this is the result?:

```
{% set result = {
  array: [
    {
      one: 'A',
      two: 'B'
    },
    {
      one: 'C',
      two: 'D'
    }
  ]
}
%}
```

Ive tried this, but it overwrites the first array rather than adding to it:

```
{% set result = stuff1|merge(stuff2) %}
```

Im using Gulp Twig: https://github.com/zimmen/gulp-twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are merging the hashes. Try merging directly the two arrays.

See the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) :

"*For hashes, the merging process occurs on the keys: if the key does not already exist, it is added but **if the key already exists, its value is overridden.***"

Try this :

```
{% set result = { array: stuff1.array|merge(stuff2.array) }%}
```

Comment: This isnt working. When I dump I can see result is     object(0) {
}

Comment: I forgot to add a key to the new hash. I edit my answer. This should work.